# Green lump in the middle of lamb meat

Tags: meat, lamb, freshness

I have bought a fresh half leg of lamb today and there was a big disgusting green lump in the middle of it's fat. I'd like to know what it is and what should I do with the meat?

Would anyone be able to help me please?

[image: lump]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have sent the picture to the New Zealand Food Safety (NZFS) and asked them about it. This is their answer:

> Thank you for contacting New Zealand Food Safety (NZFS) regarding your
> enquiry about the strange lump which you found in your piece of lamb
> meat.
>
> I have sent these photos to experts within the team who have looked
> over them.
>
> They have confirmed that it is most likely a lymph node, due to the
> grey/brown appearance and placement within the fatty area of the meat.
> Lymph nodes is considered a very normal element of the carcass and the
> ones seen in these pictures appear healthy. Unhealthy/abnormal lymph
> nodes (enlarged, hard, or full of pus) may have a very small risk if
> they were handed raw, but these would typically be discovered and
> removed by routine post mortem inspections.
>
> Because these lymph nodes appears healthy, the expert’s advice is that
> the meat is safe for consumption.

I have chosen this as the right answer, because it was a response from the officials, otherwise, @moscafj's answer was right.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not a butcher, but I believe that is just a gland between the muscle structure.  It may be off-putting to look at, but it's not harmful.  If I am portioning the meat, I'll just remove it with other sinew.

Comment: Yeah, I've helped butchering an ox once, the meat of which was to be sold, and found several of these. They need to be removed (as everything abnormal within meat), but are not affecting the quality of the surroundings. Just cut around a bit.

Answer (score 2):

I buy organic lamb leg joints and find these all the time in the fat.
I always check the fat now and take them out.
Not because I think they are especially harmful, as they have no smell or anything of that nature but because they look a bit off putting.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is a gland found in the leg of lamb. it should be removed before cooking so that the lamb can taste mild and delicious. this gland makes the cooked lamb have a gamey strong taste.